# Virtualhost Wildcard Subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

We have one static IP on which we have routed our company website. We have setup a local machine on windows with WAMP to run our testing server.

We want virtual hosts to test our different apps. However, when creating subdomains, we have a new project which uses wildcard subdomains. How can we create the wildcard subdomains in VirtualHosts.

We use,

```
 NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin admin@test
    DocumentRoot "E:/Wamp/www/corporate"
    ServerName  companysite.com
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin admin@test
    DocumentRoot "E:/Wamp/www/project"
    ServerName  project.companysite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin admin@test
    DocumentRoot "E:/Wamp/www/project"
    ServerName  *.project.companysite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

However, the last * wildcard does not work. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are using this instead, and the above is just shorthand:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
```

Then...

ServerAlias works with wildcards...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@test
    DocumentRoot "E:/Wamp/www/project"
    ServerName  www.project.companysite.com
    ServerAlias *.project.companysite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Though you might have other configuration issues that could cause this to not take effect. I know WampDeveloper is set up for this to work, XAMPP probably too. Could try one of them.

Comment: Yes, server aliases worked perfect. Thank you for that.

Comment: @Khuram, please mark this as the answer so others with a similar issue know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the syntax for `ServerName`:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#servername

It doesn't mention that it supports any sort of wilcard.

The only way to have a "default" host is to use the fact that Apache will load the *first*  [`<VirtualHost>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#virtualhost) block when there isn't any ServerName directive that matches the `Host` header.

Comment: Hi, we have several projects of this nature with multiple wildcard domains. If we make one of them default then other might not load? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone else who may stumble upon this question there is a simple step-by-step tutorial on setting up subdomains and virtual hosts for Wamp here: http://www.itutorblog.com/2011/06/how-to-create-a-subdomain-on-wamp/

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.